# How to create a navbar/left nav/sidenav in angularjs where each nav displays data from json files

Tags: angularjs, json, sidenav

I'm trying to build an app similar to the [phonecat app](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) but with slight variations. instead of a dropdown menu which sorts by in 2 ways - (1) Alphabetical order and (2) Newest whereas in my app, I'm having different categories/brands. And I'm trying to display each category via json data, which is not happening.

Suppose there are 4 brands Lenovo, Nokia, Samsung and LG. I have a json file phones which has these 4 brands and each brand has different phone models as json files, which has details like, product links and image urls,etc. Now I have a nav bar to the left with these 4 brands. On click of each brand, only the phones  related to that particular brand should be displayed. Using dropdown works well but I need it in nav bar.

Current working code:

```
<p>Segments:
        <select ng-model="searchText.id">
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option value="leNovo">Lenovo</option>
          <option value="noKia">Nokia</option>
          <option value="samSung">Samsung</option>
          <option value="lG">LG</option>
        </select> 
</p>

<!-- Body -->
<div class="col-md-10">
      <!--Body content-->

      <ul class="phones">
        <li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones | filter:searchText | orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp"
            class="thumbnail phone-list-item">
          <a href="#!/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb">
            <img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}" alt="{{phone.name}}" />
          </a>
          <a href="#!/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
          <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: can you eloborate your requirement?

Comment: the above code works well for a dropdown but I require a left/side nav where on click on a brand, the phones relevant to that brand only will be displayed. Filtering is where i need a hand.